# frame layout on main frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to adjust the subframes layout on the mainframe. As a beginner and as understand I have tried to sort out, but it is not giving the expected result.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("1390x700+0+0")
root.title("Top Frame")
root.configure(background = "white")
# layout all of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
#################################################################################
#Frames
#################################################################################
Header_F = Frame(root, bd = 10, pady = 5)
Header_F.grid(row =0, column =0, sticky = W+E)


Components_F = Frame(root,  bd = 10, width =500, height = 400)
Components_F.grid(row= 1, column = 0, sticky = NW, pady = 10)
Components_F.grid_propagate(False)

Communication_F = Frame(root, width = 100, height = 100)
Communication_F.grid(column = 1 , row = 1 , sticky = W )
Communication_F.grid_propagate(False)
```

Actual Result:
[This is the image of actually result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjYub.png)

Expected Result:

[This is the Expected Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGO3n.png)

Comment: what's about when you comment out the 2 lines:
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

Comment: @MediaEU, yes it is working if comment out the 2 lines:root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1) root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1). But if try to add the one more frame which should place under communication frame and beside the components frame, it is not placing in the right place. and Even the header frame getting the shrink to components frame. I think when it comes to managing frames on another frame, I need to use place geometry management instead of pack and grid. Am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("1390x700+0+0")
root.title("Top Frame")
root.configure(background = "white")
# layout all of the main containers
#root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
#root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
#################################################################################
#Frames
#################################################################################
Header_F = Frame(root, bd = 10,  height = 40)
Header_F.grid(row =0, column =0, sticky = W+E)


Components_F = Frame(root,  bd = 10, width =500, height = 400)
Components_F.grid(row= 1, column = 0, sticky = NW, pady = 10,padx = 10)
Components_F.grid_propagate(False)

Communication_F = Frame(root, width = 100, height = 100)
Communication_F.grid(column = 1 , row = 1, sticky = NW, pady = 10 )
Communication_F.grid_propagate(False)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes it is working if comment out the 2 lines:root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1) root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1). But if try to add the one more frame which should place under communication frame and beside the components frame, it is not placing in the right place. and Even the header frame getting the shrink to components frame. I think when it comes to managing frames on another frame, I need to use place geometry management instead of pack and grid. Am i correct?